# Popup position relative to table y-Position

Tags: html, css

is it possible that the popup appears always at the same height than the table? If the table moves down the popup should also move down. Or is it possible to add a fourth column and display the popup inside there? Or is there a better approach?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
        #matrix table {
            width:300px;
            border-collapse:collapse;
        }

        #matrix td {
            border:1px solid black;
        }

        #matrix td:hover {
          background-color: #ff0000;
        }

        #matrix td span {
            display: none;
        }

        #matrix td:hover span {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 8px;
            left: 310px;
            width: 100px;
            background: #e5e5e5;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="matrix">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>1<span>Further information 1</span></td>
                <td>2<span>Further information 2</span></td>
                <td>3<span>Further information 3</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4<span>Further information 4</span></td>
                <td>5<span>Further information 5</span></td>
                <td>6<span>Further information 6</span></td>
           </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7<span>Further information 7</span></td>
                <td>8<span>Further information 8</span></td>
                <td>9<span>Further information 9</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following on  #matrix td:hover span:

> display: inline;

and remove the:

> top: 8px;

;

```css
        #matrix table {
            width:300px;
            border-collapse:collapse;
        }

        #matrix td {
            border:1px solid black;
        }

        #matrix td:hover {
          background-color: #ff0000;
        }

        #matrix td span {
            display: none;
        }

        #matrix td:hover span {
            display: inline;
            position: absolute;
            left: 310px;
            width: 100px;
            background: #e5e5e5;
        }
```

```html
    <div id="matrix">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>1<span>Further information 1</span></td>
                <td>2<span>Further information 2</span></td>
                <td>3<span>Further information 3</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4<span>Further information 4</span></td>
                <td>5<span>Further information 5</span></td>
                <td>6<span>Further information 6</span></td>
           </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>7<span>Further information 7</span></td>
                <td>8<span>Further information 8</span></td>
                <td>9<span>Further information 9</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
    </div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is relative to the rows y-position I want it always at the y-position of the first row.

Comment: sorry, missunderstood you question, thought you want the popup to be same hight as the hovered td.